# Open a browser instance from BOT and get the response from the browser

Tags: botframework

Is it possible to program something like integration of payment gateway from within a BOT and get the response back inside the BOT program.

If I make a shopping BOT, can I open a browser with amount and other details from the BOT, that takes all the card details and get the response back with success/failure and transaction number in the BOT session.

Thanks

Comment: I doubt bots on any platform support this directly. It's not the best UX, but maybe you could send a link to the payment page to the user? Also, Facebook just introduced in-chat-payments, I imagine they might make that available for bots in the future (that's channel specific though).

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly straightforward with PayPal (with the caveat that I haven't tried it yet):

1. Create a [Payment Button](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/create_payment_button/), and display in your chat (either as text or a clickable image depending on the channel).
2. Create an endpoint for Paypal's [Instant Payment Notification](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) on your Bot so it can tell when the payment has been processed